# What does index()" mean in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, indexing, laravel-5

I have this code `$table->integer('card_id')->unsigned()->index();` in a table that I created using Laravel framework. Just to make sure what does the `index()`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's the way to say to the Laravel Migration to add indices to that column, in order to get faster results when searching through that particular column.

It's a common procedure in DB design when building tables. Just "index" some particular columns if you plan to make searchs in the table using those columns.

I just realized you added that "indexing" tag to your question and that the description of that tag answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

**A little bit more explanation to the answer:**
It means the database server will create, well, an 'index' on that column. It makes queries faster for that column - so usually you'd use it on your primary key for instance. But maybe you find out you're looking up users by their email address a lot so you might add an index to that too.

There is a small performance hit for the database server maintaining the index (it has to update the index when you write a record to the db) - so you usually use them only where needed.

Comment: Your first paragraph just restates what's in the accepted answer. Your last sentence is a good point but is not sufficient for an answer. It should be a comment on the accepted answer instead.