# define index and rebuild it by code in spring boot like migrations in laravel

Tags: laravel, spring-boot, database-migration, nebula-graph

we can define the index in Nebula graph by nebula graph studio manually

[image: define index in nebula graph by nebula graph studio manually]

how can I do this with a standard migration seeder as we have in other standard frameworks like [Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350263/what-does-index-mean-in-laravel#:%7E:text=It%27s%20the%20way%20to%20say,the%20table%20using%20those%20columns.)?

I have a spring boot and I want to know more about solutions to define it automatically.